# Hosting Web Service/WCF Service?

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, wcf, cloud

I'm new to Windows Azure and I'm trying to deploy my web application to Windows Azure.
In my app I used some web services, now I would like to know how can I build them in windows azure and include that web reference in my web app?

Some tutorials said that I have to import my current web service into a Cloud Service Project as a WebRole but in my web serivce folder, there's no csproj file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I just have to create a new `Window Azure Project` and add a `WCF Service Web Role`, copy my old files in the old Web Service (maybe change a little bit if it's ASMX) then host it the same way as web application. And voila, everything is ok now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a WebRole for a web service, but you can use a WorkerRole though.

Take a look on this:

http://www.devproconnections.com/article/windows-azure-platform3/Hosting-WCF-Services-on-Azure-101.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I said above, my current web service doesn't have a csproj file, so how can I add it as a WebRole/WorkerRole? :-<

Comment: Create a new project and simply add the code there. Otherwise you will have to create the cloud project almost manually. You can add an object derivated from RoleEntryPoint in your WCF project, and add the project by hand to the .csdef file, but create a new project will be the easiest.