# How to deploy a web application with WCF as a cloud service using Windows Azure Pack?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, architecture

We want to develop a web application as a cloud service on windows Azure. The application has the following architecture:

[image]

This application was a simple line of business winforms application, where any customer could purchase and use it. Now our company decided to redesign it as a web application where many customers can work on it in the same time. The core application will stay the same, just some simple customizations, it does some simple tasks in the database and sending emails and other things.

Now, Our company decided that we need to use windows Azure to publish the web application as a could service. We don't need to use any of the Azure storage nor SQL Azure database services, instead we will use our datacenter's storages and database. We just need to deploy the application as a cloud service, and we don't know where to start. I couldn't understand how to use windows Azure cloud services in this application. So my questions are:

- **Is this architecture valid with windows Azure? And where would be the role of Windows Azure and its cloud services in this archticture?**
- We don't need to host the application on Microsoft datacenters, instead we need to use it in our datacenter, when I searched I found the [**Windows Azure Pack for Windows Server**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296435.aspx), so can we use it so that we can host it in our datacenter? Does we need any extra cost consideration to use it? Where to start to use in our application?
- I found some posts and tutorials (like [this one here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388806/hosting-web-service-wcf-service)) saying that I just have to create a new Window Azure Project and add a WCF Service Web Role, copy the application files from the old Web Service then host the same as a web application. Is that true? Is windows Azure just involved in the deployment and it doesn't has any effects in the internal architecture of the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy both your UI and Service back-end to Azure Web Roles. If you have any remaining WinForms application, they still can connect to the Service back-end. I would recommend that you also deploy your database to Azure if possible to improve performance and reduce latency. You can either use Azure SQL Database or you can create a SQL Server VM.

There are various interesting options to deploy layered applications to Windows Azure. You can read more about it here. http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.com/2014/01/layered-applications-and-windows-azure.html

You can also checkout a simple sample here
http://cloudsample.codeplex.com